# Setting Up Azure's Application Insight in MVC Application Locally - Throws an Application Error (with empty exception)

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, azure-application-insights

was wondering if anyone experienced this issue..

Followed this example on how to set up application insight within a MVC .NET Project locally:

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net)

Project builds without any issues, but while running it locally and trying to bring up a default page in the browser... my project throws an error in the Application Error Method within Global.asax

[application error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDJdK.png)

Followed the steps correctly, added instrumental key to the application insights config file, so I am not sure what else needs to be adjusted.. Rolled back to previous state removing AI settings - everything works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Tried it in MS VS 2017,2019 with the same result.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tested in our local environment following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#create-a-basic-aspnet-web-app) steps to enable application insights for the MVC local project which is working fine & able to see those application insights telemetry  in the azure portal as well .

We have created a default MVC project in visual studio 2019 & added
application insight instrumentation key in the applicationinsights.config file as shown below

[image]

In the Global.Asax file we dont see any method that you have shared in the screen shot above. Here is our project global.asax file config

[image]

After running the application in our local visual Studio 2019 we are able to see the metric in the azure portal as shown in below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feed back, the error issue was resolved. Project was missing missing runtime assembly references.

Comment: This ticket can be closed, error is resolved. Now i am working on the following issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037384/azures-application-insight-in-mvc-project-live-metrics-your-app-is-offline-or  Thanks Venkatesh

Comment: Just did, by the way, did you get Live Metrics feature to work ?

Comment: yes , we able to capture live metric using the default application insights Nuget Package as discussed in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037384/azures-application-insight-in-mvc-project-live-metrics-your-app-is-offline-or