# Azure's Application Insight in MVC Project - Live Metrics Your App is offline or using an older SDK

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, azure-application-insights

hopefully someone can point it out what is the issue here.. and thank you in advance.

Trying to get Live Metrics working with my MVC Project running locally.
Followed these directions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net

Verified that application insights contains all the links, verified data is being passed via fiddler.

Azure's Application Map is showing an instance running from my local environment
[Application Insights - Application Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuMlO.png)

Live Metrics is still showing the message that the app is offline
[Application Insight - Live Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLWBO.png)

List of Packages in the Bin
[BIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFrCQ.png)

Background:

- MS Visual Studio 2017
- Project MVC
- Framework 4.5.2

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you use Fiddler to see whether the app reaches out Live Metrics endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tested in our local environment following the [documentation steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net) to enable application insights  for the MVC local project which is working fine & able to see those application insights telemetry in the azure portal as well.

We have created 2 default MVC project in visual studio 2019 & added application insight instrumentation key in the `applicationinsightsconfig file`

- As suggested in the documentation, In our 1st project, we have upgraded the NuGet packages of application insights from (2.15 to 2.19) newer versions.

In portal under the live metrics widget we are seeing the  same message "Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK"

[image]

Here are the list of NuGet packages we have used in our project & there respective versions.

[image]

- In our 2nd project, we haven't upgraded the NuGet packages of application insights to newer versions but are able to capture the live metrics as shown below.

[image]

Here are the list of NuGet packages we have used in our project & there respective versions

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will give it a try. Accepted